# jslint Expected ']' and instead saw '/'

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am getting the exception like

> jslint Expected ']' and instead saw '/'.

```
function returnFilePath(fullPath) {
    var objRE = new RegExp(/([^//]+)\\/);
    var stringPath = objRE.exec(fullPath);
    if (stringPath == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return stringPath[1];
    }
}
```

Not able to find the solution for this.

Comment: The regex is ending early on the second / character. You need to escape it with a \

Comment: @cricket_007 it is not ending early, in a characters set `/` does not have any special properties/meaning.

Comment: @zerkms Do you not need to surround the regex in / characters? For example, `/[A-Z]/`?

Comment: @cricket_007 you do need for sure. My point was that if it's within `[]` you don't need to escape it, since it's just a character, not a delimiter.

Comment: @zerkms Right... So the linter is seeing `/([^/`,  and erroring because the second / there has signaled the end of the expression

Comment: @cricket_007 then the linter is stupid, since it's not an error. "has signaled the end of the expression" --- no it has not. **within a character set `/` does not have any special properties**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your regex is invalid:
[image]
(Screenshot from: https://regex101.com/)

What pattern are you trying to match?
Could it be:

```
([^\/]+)\\
```

Comment: "is invalid" --- what makes you thinking so? It is syntactically correct for sure

Comment: @Bruno Garcia It's valid. Just try it in the browser console. regex101.com defaults to pcre (which shows it as invalid), but if you switch it to JavaScript it shows that it is valid.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of the exact rule that is flagging this error (there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on what the rules actually are), but you can get rid of the error by escaping the slashes in the square brackets:

```
var objRE = new RegExp(/([^\/\/]+)\\/);
```